# What is happening to my Google ads? They are askew!

Tags: google-adsense

Since this morning, one of my Google Adsense ad units has taken on a very strange appearance. (This is only happening with text ads; display ads appear normally.)

[image: AdSense leaderboard ad unit with unusual appearance]

You can see this for yourself live at http://myip.addr.space/

[image: AdSense responsive leaderboard ad unit askew]

As you can see, the ad is no longer horizontal. It's... askew. Just like the [Google easter egg](https://www.google.com/search?q=askew).

[image: Google askew]

Why is this happening? Can I stop it? (*Should* I stop it? Maybe this is one weird trick to get people to read the ads and click on them...)

Comment: Beats me! This is a new one!!

Comment: Do you have a live URL? Have you checked the CSS in Developer Tools?

Comment: wow! How did you managed to do this? :D

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat This can be seen at http://myip.addr.space/ . I had no reason to hide it, except I did not want to appear overly promotional :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and the ad is perfectly horizontal for me.

[image: non askew ad]

If you are still having this issue there are a few things you can check. Right click the ad and click "Inspect element". In the Dev Tools window, look through each of the elements (such as the `<body>` tag in the iframe) to see if you can find one with the CSS applied (it will be something like `transform: rotate(1deg)`).

If you find it, make a note of the CSS file it comes from. If it's one of your own files for the site then you can find the line in your CSS and remove it.

It may also be the result of a browser extension such as Stylish, which can add custom CSS to your web pages. Try using incognito mode, or try disabling your extensions one by one until it fixes the problem. Maybe a friend is playing a prank on you and installed that on your computer.

Comment: #adunit does indeed contain a `transform: rotate(1deg);` which is being served from Google's https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads? (query string omitted as it doesn't fit in the comment). So Google is definitely doing it, at least to me.

Comment: That is strange. The only thing I can think of is that it's some kind of test by Google to see if wonky ads get more attention and more clicks. I'd suggest contacting Adsense if you can, in case there is some error on their side.